# Android-NDK how to compile this code? | Beginner

Tags: android-ndk, android.mk

A developer has published its code in GitHub for anyone who wants to create their server for SAMP Android (a project in development that allows them to play Android GTA online).

Code Link: https://github.com/4x11/SAMP-Android

I want to know which program to use and the right commands to compile this code. As far as I know, this is an NDK build code ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by reading the NDK guide.

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/

Then since the code makes use of the old ndk-build makefiles,

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-build

And the respective integration samples,

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/other-builds/ndkbuild